# Add related objects to inline

Tags: django

I have a OneToOneField with my User and UserProfile model. And a second model transaction. When a transaction is created it takes a foreignKey User object.

What I'd like is with the OneToOneField UserProfile to display the transaction objects related to that user. With the str representation of the transaction object.

So that it will look like this:

[image]

Another example is, lets say my db is

```
userid_id  transaction_id
   2            1
   2            2
   4            3
   4            4
```

Then whenever I view user 2 from the admin panel, I will only see transaction 1 and 2.

I'm not very clear on how to display onetomany relations or in general specify which objects to display in the admin panel.

```
class transaction(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    investment_point = models.ForeignKey(investment_point, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ingameName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='NotSet')  

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

And in my admin panel

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline, )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: So... You want to output inline Transaction objects (by `__str__` call) related to UserProfile object in Django admin, right?

Comment: @KidBinary Not by __str__ call. Well I'm not sure how you'd call them. The __str__ was just to display the object visualy. I just want to display the transactions objects. Related to the User in UserProfile

Comment: Allright, and it should be done like - User model, inline UserProfiles, and inline Transactions binded to UserProfiles?

Comment: @KidBinary Dosen't have to be inline Transactions. If Transactions could be displayed in the inline UserProfile that would be great. But again I lack any understand of how to approach this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Django Admin does not support nested inlines (and as I understood, you need nested inlines). However, there are couple workarounds.

**Using third-party packages**

You can simply use [Django-super-inlines](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-super-inlines) package, following installation procedure and examples on the package GitHub page.

Also, there is [django-nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) to aid you as well.

**Using two `admin` classes for the same model and linking them**

Instead of making nested inlines with third-party packages, we can define a link from `UserProfile` to `Transaction`.

To achieve this, you need to make two `admin` classes of `UserProfile` model, to extend both base `ModelAdmin` and `TabularInline`, and write a simple custom method:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Main admin model
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TransactionInline, ]

# Register it as admin
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)

# This will show a reference
class UserProfileReferenceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'
    readonly_fields = ('reference_link', )

    def reference_link(self, instance):
        if instance.id:
            # Change 'yourapp' with your app name
            reference_url = reverse(
                'admin:yourapp_transaction_change', args=(instance.id,)
            )
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">Transaction</a>' % reference_url
        return ''

    reference_link.allow_tags = True

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileReferenceInline, )

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

This is just an example of how it could be done, and the code above might require a couple of tweaks to fit your project.